# Linkify text file in Linux

Tags: html, linux, url, awk, printf

I have parsed all rows containing urls from a text file and appended line breaks, and I want to make the links clickable in a new file.

How do I append `<a href>` -tags around only the urls, using standard linux tools, preferably awk?
It needs to be automatable in cron.

For example,

source file **chaturls.txt**:

```
    12:30 <user> check this: https://link.to/stuff.jpg</br>
    13:47 <user4> https://another.link.lol eyyyy</br>
```

desired output in new file, **chatlinkified.html**:

```
12:30 <user> check this: <a href='https://link.to/stuff.jpg'>https://link.to/stuff.jpg</a></br>
13:47 <user4> <a href='https://another.link.lol'>https://another.link.lol</a> eyyyy</br>
```

I tried `awk '{printf "<a href=\"%s\">%s</a><br>", $0,$0}' chaturls.txt > chatlinkified.html`, but this makes the whole line an (invalid) clickable link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sed -E 's@(https?://[^[:space:]/$.?#].[^[:space:]<]*)@<a href="\1">\1</a>@g' chaturls.txt > chatlinkified.html
```

You can use sed and refer back to the matched group with `\1`. NB. here I separate using the @ instead of / (as in s/../../g), you are free the use any character and this saves some escapes.

The regex for finding the URL does some validation checks for the first character after the https?:// and then proceeds the match until a space or the starting bracket of another tag.

You can if you want to use a more simpler regex for the url like, given in one of the comments `https?://[^ ]*)` which doesn't include this small validation.

You can find more extensive validated url regex here: https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex (But you have to convert from PHP regex to sed extended regex)

Comment: Can you add some comments about your regular expression?  I stopped when i got some answer looking OK, when doing `sed -E 's@(https?://[^ ]*)@<a href="\1">\1</a>@g' chaturls.txt` 